# How to filter this type of non-standard characters in Chinese?

Tags: python, cjk

```
④眼袋手术又称眼下脂肪重新排列
中药仙草玉容膜又称懒人神器
```

The first character ④, the flower and such like are trouble maker. I have code to remove emojis, but these characters are not in the emoji range. How to effectively get rid of them?

Comment: Why is it a setback that they are not "in the emoji range"? Do you *only* know how to remove emoji, but no other characters?

Comment: @usr2564301 Unicode seems a big thing. So how to find their code range for those examples?

Comment: You don't need a range. Just copy those characters and paste them into a search/replace string. Python should be able to handle that just fine.

Comment: You mean compile a list of those tokens and remove them? But there are a lot such tokens on social media forums. Is there a systematic way to detect?

Comment: Okay – it seems you are assuming because there is a specific range for 'emoji', you think there is a range for 'miscellaneous weird characters' as well. That is not the case. But if you suspect there may be more encircled digits, for example, you can create a range for those: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/enclosed_alphanumerics/utf8test.htm Repeat for others; look up their Unicode block and decide what range they fall in.

Comment: Great! how to specify code range for those encircled digits? I want to remove them all automatically? I am a newbie for unicode code